# EOFException in objectinputstream readobject

Tags: java, objectinputstream, eofexception

i want to make a server  client application. i set everything up and i get this error. i want the app to wait till i get more data.

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
```

on the line:

```
listener.Received(inputstream.readObject(), id.ID);
```

Server code:

```
isrunning = true;
    Thread input = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket(LocalPort);
                while(isrunning){
                    Socket socket = Server.accept();
                    ObjectOutputStream outputstream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    ObjectInputStream inputstream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    Object obj = inputstream.readObject();
                    if(obj instanceof ID){
                        ID id = (ID) obj;
                        if(connctedChecker(id.ID)){
                            ID myid = new ID(ID, LocalIP, LocalPort);
                            outputstream.writeObject(myid);
                            connect(id.IP, id.Port);
                            listener.Connected(id.ID);
                            do{
                                listener.Received(inputstream.readObject(), id.ID);
                            }while(socket.isConnected());
                            listener.Disconnected(id.ID);
                            closeConnection(id.ID);
                        }
                    }
                    inputstream.close();
                    outputstream.close();
                    socket.close();
                }
                Server.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    input.start();
```

Client code:

```
output = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                socket = new Socket(RemoteIP, RemotePort);
                inputstream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                outputstream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                ID id = new ID(ID, LocalIP, LocalPort);
                outputstream.writeObject(id);
                outputstream.flush();
                Object obj = inputstream.readObject();
                if(obj instanceof ID){
                    ID inid = (ID) obj;
                    RemoteID = inid.ID;
                }
                while(socket.isConnected()){
                    Object object = queue.take();
                    outputstream.writeObject(object);
                    outputstream.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

the listener:

```
public class Listener {

public void Connected(UUID ID){

}

public void Received(Object object, UUID ID){

}

public void Disconnected(UUID ID){

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
do{
    listener.Received(inputstream.readObject(), id.ID);
} while(socket.isConnected());
```

Unless your socket/inputstream has an infinite number of objects to send, it is going to run out of objects sooner or later. That's what has happened. It says so right in the javadoc for [`EOFException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html).

> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.
>
> This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of stream. Note that many other input operations return a special value on end of stream rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Since the `EOFException` is to be expected from this operation, I'd surround it with a try/catch and handle the exception. I don't know if you'd want to break out of the loop and continue on as if the socket had closed, or if you'd want to sit there and wait until more data came along. That's up to you.

Comment: i want it to wait till more data comes along

Comment: @TheGathron That's exactly what t will already does: it blocks. If it throws `EOFException` the peer has closed the connection, so there will never be any more data on it.

Comment: NB `while (socket.isConnected()` is not a test for end of stream, or liveness of the connection. It doesn't magically become false. Ever.

Answer (score -1):

Are all your Objects used in WorkerMessageToMaster serializable, as well as WorkerMessageToMaster itself? Every Object you want to send with ObjectStreams have to implement serializable, and all children of it have to have it implemented. String, as well as primitive datatypes (int, float etc) are serializable without you needing to do anything. But if you use your own classes, they have to implement serializable.

Comment: The exception is `EOFException`, not `NotSerializableException`. And implemented interfaces are inherited by subclasses automatically, without them having to be explicitly restated.